# Julia syntax to include multiple files on single line of code

Tags: include, julia

Julia 1.5.3 on Ubuntu

This works for me

```
julia> include("par1.jl")
julia> include("fun1.jl")
```

but when I put multiple files in the parenthesis,

```
julia> include("par1.jl" , "fun1.jl")
```

I get an error.  Is there syntax that will allow multiple file include on one line or am I limited to one per line? Thx. J

Answer (score 3):

Typically one includes one file per line, e.g. because the order of inclusion is usually relevant, so it is visually better to do this this way. Also in this way if something errors when you do `include` you have a cleaner information what has failed.

You could write something like:

```
foreach(include, ("par1.jl" , "fun1.jl"))
```

which will perform the inclusion in the sequence of passed arguments, but it is an implementation detail that  is not a part of `foreach` documentation.

An even shorter way to write it would be:

```
include.(("par1.jl" , "fun1.jl"))
```

(this operation has a side effect as it produces a result and also the order of operations performed is an implementation detail that is not guaranteed by the documentation)